# How to align items in RowLayout

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to align `Rectangle`s in a `RowLayout` left to right. In below code example two `Rectangle`s share additional space instead stack one after another. I used `Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft` in `RowLayout` level and `Rectangle` level, but non of those two ways didn't change the view at all.

```
Item {
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 2
        

        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft

            Text {
                text: "Hello world"
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft

            Text {
                text: "Hello world"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In following images black border indicates the `RowLayout` and red border is the `Rectangle`s.

## Actual

[image: Acual layout]

## Expected

[image: Expected layout]

Comment: You might be happier using a `Row` instead of the `RowLayout` - for that is the normal behavior of the `Row`.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me to use a horizontal RowLayout when the children Items have static widths. Use a Row instead and bind the children's heights to the Row's height.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The documentation states regarding the `Layout.alignment`:

> This property allows you to specify the alignment of an item within the **cell(s)** it occupies.

You can simply add a filler item at the end like such:

```
RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 2


    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        color: 'red'

        Text {
            text: "Hello world"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        color: 'green'

        Text {
            text: "Hello world"
        }
    }

    Item {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
}
```

But alternatively use that:

```
Row {
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 2


    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }

        color: 'red'

        Text {
            text: "Hello world"
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        color: 'green'

        Text {
            text: "Hello world"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of Layouts you shouldn't use width property for Items inside a Layout. Instead you should use Layout.preferredWidth/Height and min/max if needed

Answer (score -1):

**You could change the spacing value to a negative like below :**

```
RowLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: -parent.width*0.6
    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        border.width:1
        border.color:"red"
        Text {
            text: "Hello world"
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        border.width:1
        border.color:"red"
        Text {
            text: "Hello world"
        }
    }

}
```